# regex for capturing all mathematical operators in python like >=, <= and ==

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
spec_op = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '**', '>', '<', '=>', '<=', '==']
```

I am writing a regex for capturing these operators from a calculation field. but `=>`, `<=`, `==` these operators would not captured.

I Tried:

```
import re
a = '(0 if ((aa+cc)<=vv) else ((aa+cc-vv)*(cv/(100+cv)))) if (aa<=vv) else ((aa - vv)*(cv/(100+cv)))'
re.findall(r"[\+|-|\*|\/|=|>|<|(>=)|(<=)|&|\||%|!|\^|\(|\)]",a)
```

it gives:

```
['(',
 '(',
 '(',
 '+',
 ')',
 '<',
 '=',
 ')',
 '(',
 '(',
 '+',
 ')',
 '*',
 '(',
 '/',
 '(',
 '+',
 ')',
 ')',
 ')',
 ')',
 '(',
 '<',
 '=',
 ')',
 '(',
 '(',
 ')',
 '*',
 '(',
 '/',
 '(',
 '+',
 ')',
 ')',
 ')']
```

How can i achieve `>=` and `<=` in final result using regex.

Comment: Put the longer ones like `>=` *first*, eg before `>`

Comment: Why not just hard code the original list of operators? Feels the simplest and most readable way

Comment: The big problem with your regex is that you are just looking for a single character in the set `\+|-|\*|\/|=|>|<|(>=)|(<=)|&|\||%|!|\^|\(|\)` because you've enclosed all your alternatives inside `[` and `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r"[<>=]=|[-+*/=><&|%!^()]",a)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EtoAm1):

```
import re
a = '(0 if ((aa+cc)<=vv) else ((aa+cc-vv)*(cv/(100+cv)))) if (aa<=vv) else ((aa - vv)*(cv/(100+cv)))'
print(re.findall(r"[<>=]=|[-+*/=><&|%!^()]",a))
# => ['(', '(', '(', '+', ')', '<=', ')', '(', '(', '+', '-', ')', '*', '(', '/', '(', '+', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(', '<=', ')', '(', '(', '-', ')', '*', '(', '/', '(', '+', ')', ')', ')']
print(list(set(re.findall(r"[<>=]=|[-+*/=><&|%!^()]",a)))) # Unique occurrences
# => ['+', '*', '(', ')', '-', '/', '<=']
```

The longer sequences in an alternation list where alternatives are not anchored must precede shorter ones. See [Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Besides, you may avoid overescaping if you use single char alternatives inside a character class where only few chars require escaping, and if you place `-` at the start or end, it can stay unescaped, too.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Do you mean the code must return unique occurrences? `list(set(re.findall(r"[<>=]=|[-+*/=><&|%!^()]",a)))`?

Comment: Does that really capture "=>"?

Comment: @Jeronimo No, because OP only asked to match `=>`, `<=` and `==`. To also match `=>` just add it: `r"=>|[<>=]=|[-+*/=><&|%!^()]"`